# How can I get the raw byte offsets of individual datasets in an HDF5 file using Python?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

The byte offsets of individual (contiguous) datasets in an HDF5 file can be determined using the [`h5ls` tool](https://docs.hdfgroup.org/hdf5/develop/_view_tools_view.html#subsecViewToolsViewContent_h5ls) distributed as part of the [HDF5 library](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/), but I have been unable to figure how to accomplish this task programmatically using Python (specifically, the [`h5py` package](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/index.html)).

I have found R's [`rhdf5` package](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html), which includes a [`h5ls` function](https://rdrr.io/bioc/rhdf5/man/h5ls.html), but `h5py` does not have anything similar as far as I can tell. I also found [How can I get raw byte offsets and bytes read from that offset using the HDF5 C API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75009735/how-can-i-get-raw-byte-offsets-and-bytes-read-from-that-offset-using-the-hdf5-c), but it has no answers and is also asking about C instead of Python.

I'm not necessarily looking for a one-line solution, just a way to access this information using Python at all. I'm not hard-set on using `h5py` specifically, either. If there's another package or solution that is able to do this better, I'd be happy to consider it.

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe the `.get_offset()` method mentioned  in the [Low-Level API](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/lowlevel.html)

Comment: Barmar, doh! Not sure how I missed that—thanks for pointing it out. If you submit this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea to use it in practice. I just saw the section name "low level", thought it might be relevant, and then the name `get_offset()` sounded just like your question. I don't actually know anything about HDF5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the low level h5py API. The `.get_offset()` method works on any dataset object. Examples below shows how to get the low level id (and offset) 2 ways: 1) by object reference and 2) by name reference..

```
# first create a simple file with 3 datasets
with h5py.File('SO_76068934.h5','w') as h5f:
    data = [float(i) for i in range (10)]
    h5f.create_dataset('ds_1', data=data)
    data = [float(i) for i in range (10,20)]
    h5f.create_dataset('ds_2', data=data)    
    data = [float(i) for i in range (20,30)]
    h5f.create_dataset('ds_3', data=data)
    
# open the file in read mode and get dataset objects, IDs and Offsets
with h5py.File('SO_76068934.h5','r') as h5f:
    # loop over root level dataset names and objects
    for ds_name, ds_obj in h5f.items():  
        # referencing dataset object:
        ds_id = ds_obj.id    # get low level dataset ID from object
        ds_off = ds_id.get_offset()  # Low-level method
        print(f'For: {ds_name}; Offset: {ds_off}')

        # referencing dataset name:
        ds_off = h5f[ds_name].id.get_offset() # get ID and offset in 1 step
        print(f'For: {ds_name}; Offset: {ds_off}\n')
```